# am getting a gradle error saying am duplicating dependencies but i cant find duplicates

Tags: android, gradle

so this are all my project dependencies can someone please point me in  the right direction and help me please. I have been removing and adding to try to solve it with no luck.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "main.itprogrammer.journo"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url = 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.10.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.10.2.jar')
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile project(':timerangepicker-library')
    compile project(':library')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0'
    compile 'pub.devrel:easygoogle:0.1+'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
}
```

the error is as follows

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:compileLint
:facebook:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:checkReleaseManifest
:facebook:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42221Library UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:prepareReleaseDependencies
:facebook:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:facebook:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:library:compileLint
:library:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:library:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:checkReleaseManifest
:library:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:library:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:library:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library UP-TO-DATE
:library:prepareReleaseDependencies
:library:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:library:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:library:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:library:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:library:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:library:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:library:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:library:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:library:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:library:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:library:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:library:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:library:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:library:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:library:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:library:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:library:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:library:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:library:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:library:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:library:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:library:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:timerangepicker-library:compileLint
:timerangepicker-library:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:timerangepicker-library:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:timerangepicker-library:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:timerangepicker-library:checkReleaseManifest
:timerangepicker-library:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:timerangepicker-library:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:timerangepicker-library:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:timerangepicker-library:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:timerangepicker-library:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:timerangepicker-library:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library UP-TO-DATE
:timerangepicker-library:prepareReleaseDependencies
:timerangepicker-library:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:timerangepicker-library:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:timerangepicker-library:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:timerangepicker-library:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:timerangepicker-library:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:timerangepicker-library:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:timerangepicker-library:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:timerangepicker-library:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:timerangepicker-library:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:timerangepicker-library:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:timerangepicker-library:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:timerangepicker-library:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:timerangepicker-library:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:timerangepicker-library:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:timerangepicker-library:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:timerangepicker-library:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:timerangepicker-library:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:timerangepicker-library:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:timerangepicker-library:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:timerangepicker-library:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:timerangepicker-library:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:timerangepicker-library:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAmulyakhareComAmulyakhareTextdrawable101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportPaletteV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebook460Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareJournoLibraryUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareJournoTimerangepickerLibraryUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:preparePubDevrelEasygoogle011Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: class name (org/groupby/parser/json/JSONArray) does not match path (org/groupby/parser/JSON/JSONArray.class)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:520)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
...while parsing org/groupby/parser/JSON/JSONArray.class
1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 5.564 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: Provide your error also ...

Comment: Your posted error does not match your title?..

Answer (score 0):

You can use gradle dependencies command

Sample:

```
gradle :app:dependencies
gradle dependencies 
gradle :master:dependencies
```

This command make map of dependencies:

```
\--- org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0
     +--- junit:junit:4.8.2 -> 4.12 (*)
     +--- org.robolectric:robolectric-annotations:3.0
     +--- org.robolectric:robolectric-resources:3.0
     |    +--- org.robolectric:robolectric-utils:3.0
     |    |    +--- org.robolectric:robolectric-annotations:3.0
     |    |    \--- com.google.android.apps.common.testing.accessibility.framework:accessibility-test-framework:1.0
     |    +--- org.robolectric:robolectric-annotations:3.0
     |    \--- com.ximpleware:vtd-xml:2.11
     +--- org.robolectric:robolectric-utils:3.0 (*)
     +--- org.robolectric:shadows-core:3.0
     |    +--- org.robolectric:robolectric-annotations:3.0
     |    +--- org.robolectric:robolectric-utils:3.0 (*)
     |    +--- org.robolectric:robolectric-resources:3.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:53.1
     |    \--- com.almworks.sqlite4java:sqlite4java:0.282
     +--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:1.46
     +--- org.ow2.asm:asm:5.0.1  
     +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:5.0.1
     |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:5.0.1
     |         \--- org.ow2.asm:asm:5.0.1
     +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:5.0.1
     |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:5.0.1 (*)
     +--- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:5.0.1
     |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:5.0.1 (*)
     +--- com.ximpleware:vtd-xml:2.11
     +--- org.apache.maven:maven-ant-tasks:2.1.3 (*)
     \--- org.apache.ant:ant:1.8.0 (*)
```

Comment: thanx andrey7mel ill try to use this solution when i get home..and post feedback later on.